# pymongo query for distinct values and case insensitive

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How to get distinct values from `mongodb` collection with `case insensitive`. with given examples I can able to find distinct values.

```
collection:location schema 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542bc237e75e4a30c2e13b7e"),"place" : ["Hyderabad"]} 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542bc238e75e4a30c2e13b7f"),"place" : ["hyderabad"]}
```

Example:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

MongoClient client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/') 
db = client.india 
collection = db.location 
doc = collection.distinct("place") 
print doc [[u'Hyderabad'],[u'hyderabad']]
```

But I need to get only one value as `hyderabad`, as value being same in two documents.

Answer (score 1):

Why is `place` an array? I guess you have > 1 values in it sometimes in real documents? Start by [unwinding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), then use [$toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) string operator in an otherwise standard compute-distinct-values aggregation pipeline:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$place" },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "$toLower" : { "$place" } } } }
])
```

Comment: @dharanikumarbodla, you should to mark answer as right answer if it helps you. `$toLower` helps me, but I have another question.